# Doctrine many to many query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, dql

I have a `Contacts` entity and a `Users` entity with *many-to-many* relationship, in order to setup favorite contacts.

I try to build a query to find if a *contact* is a favorite of a *user*. Doctrine returns the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 81 near 'favoris = :user': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

Here is my query :

```
    public function isFavori(users $user, contacts $contacts) {

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $query = $qb
        ->select('1')
        ->from('contactsBundle:contacts', 'c')
        ->join('contactsBundle:users', 'f', 'WITH', 'c.favoris = :user')
        ->where('c = :contact')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('contact', $contacts)
    ;
    $querystring = $qb->getQuery();
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Here is the join annotation from the `Contact` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Curuba\contactsBundle\Entity\users", inversedBy="contactsfavoris")
 *
 */
private $favoris;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up in creating my own class. This is also required to get more flexibility to manipulate the query when using this bundle : [APYDataGridBundle](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle).

So here is what I have:

`contacts` entity class, with:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Curuba\contactsBundle\Entity\contactsfavoris", mappedBy="contact", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $usersFavoris;
```

`users` entity class, with:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Curuba\contactsBundle\Entity\contactsfavoris", mappedBy="user")
 *
 */
private $contactsfavoris;
```

`contactsfavoris` entity class, with:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="contacts", inversedBy="usersFavoris")
 */
private $contact;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="users", inversedBy="contactsfavoris")
 */
private $user;
```

The query:

```
public function isFavori(users $user, contacts $contacts) {

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $userid = $user->getId();
    $contactId = $contacts->getId();
    $query = $qb
        ->select('1')
        ->from('contactsBundle:contactsfavoris','cf')
        ->where('cf.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('cf.contact = :contact')
        ->setParameter('user', $userid)
        ->setParameter('contact', $contacts)
    ;

    try {
        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result = 0;
    }
    if ($result == 1 ) {
        $favori = true;
    } else {
        $favori = false;
    }

    return $favori;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a JoinTable to your ManyToManyAssociation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Curuba\contactsBundle\Entity\users", inversedBy="contactsfavoris")
 * @JoinTable(name="user_contact_favoris")
 */
private $favoris;
```

And now your query:

```
public function isFavori(users $user, contacts $contact) {

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->select('1')
        ->from('user_contact_favoris', 'f')
        ->innerJoin('contactsBundle:contacts', 'c', 'WITH', 'f.contact = :contact')
        ->innerJoin('contactsBundle:users', 'u', 'WITH', 'f.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('contact', $contact)
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. Why should we specify JoinTable name? Doctrine is creating it automatically? Do you mean that querying objects only works on One-To-One or One-To-Many relationships ?

Comment: It might be the case because if I do ``->andWhere('f.id = :user')`` then it works. The only difference is that I use an id instead of the object itself...

Comment: When I try your sugggestion, it triggers the following error: ``Class 'Curuba\contactsBundle\Entity\contacts_users' is not defined.``. And when I try with ``contactsBundle:contacts_users`` it doesn't work either. 
Do you I need to actually create the class to describe the Many to Many relationship myself ?